# TypeError: cb is not a function - with callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

I am trying to get a list of users from a database and when this has completed I want to list these users. I have tried to use a callback but getting the error that `TypeError: cb is not a function`

```
var getAllUsers = function(users) {
    console.log(users)
}

function checkForUsers(table, cb) {
    connection.query('SELECT * from ' + table, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            users.push({id: id});   
            if(i == (rows.length - 1)) {
                cb(users)
            } 
        }
    });
}

checkForUsers('users',getAllUsers(users));
```

Comment: Try: checkForUsers('users', getAllUsers);

Comment: Would it be ok if I add it as an answer?

Comment: sure please do. i will give you the green tick. can you explain why you don't need to pass the argument?

Comment: added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of:

```
checkForUsers('users',getAllUsers(users));
```

Use:

```
checkForUsers('users',getAllUsers);
```

The reason emphasised:

> We can pass functions around like variables and return them in
>   functions and use them in other functions. When we pass a callback
>   function as an argument to another function, **we are only passing the
>   function definition**. We are not executing the function in the
>   parameter. In other words, we aren’t passing the function with the
>   trailing pair of executing parenthesis () like we do when we are
>   executing a function.

**[Source](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)**